# Getting error while executing AWS ssm document using powershell and YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, yaml, aws-ssm

I have written AWS ssm document using PowerShell and YAML. See below code

```
schemaVersion: '2.2'
description: Command Document Example JSON Template
mainSteps:
  - action: aws:runPowerShellScript
    name: R21AutomationSSM
    inputs:
      runCommand: [
            $logPath: 'C:\SALogs'
            ]
```

Getting below error while executing this document:

> Invalid format in
> plugin properties map[runCommand:$logPath: 'C:\SALogs'];
>
> error json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field
> RunScriptPluginInput.RunCommand of type []string

I am not sure that is this related to yaml or any other ?
Please help.

Comment: Something similar here  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330403/aws-download-content-in-yaml

Comment: Thanks but it does not help

Comment: Probably need to replace  with  $logPath: `'C:\\SALogs'`

Comment: No, this also does not work

Comment: Pls do share what eventually worked here .